# Time taken:Row major sum Column major sum

Tags: c

I have come across this question and I am a bit confused. Two codes have been given and it is asked which would take more time or whether both will take same time. The codes were:

```
void sumCal(int n,int a[][]){
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         sum=sum+a[i][j];
      }
   }
}
```

or

```
void sumCal(int n,int a[][]){
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         sum=sum+a[j][i];
      }
   }
}
```

As far as I know it depends on the memory layout, whether the memory is laid out row major wise or column major wise. Is this the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One primary issue is indeed whether the matrix is laid out in row-major or column-major format.  That is defined by the C standard; it is not something that is left up to compiler writers. The other primary issue is the size of the array; if it is small enough to fit in cache memory, then it isn't critical which mechanism you use, but if it is too big to fit in cache, then one mechanism is vastly quicker than the other.

Which is it?  Well, a quick search on Wikipedia for [Row-major Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) shows that C uses row-major order.

Answer (score 1):

Im not actually sure the code will compile first of all, because the dimension needs to be included in the function parameter declaration for arrays for each dimension after the first.

Anyway, C is row major (meaning elements within rows are stored contiguously in memory, and actually for a multidimensional array in C the entire array is contiguous), so the first option might be faster, because the inner loop traverses over a row by iterating over the columns.

Lastly you need to know how big the arrays are and how big the L1 cache is on the CPU you're using. If the array can fit within the L1 cache then both options should run at the same speed, since no cache lines will get ejected before theyre finished being used.

Comment: +1: You're correct; the code won't compile without a dimension for every array dimension except (perhaps) the first.  In C99, you can write: `void sumByCols(int n, int a[n][n]) { ... }` and `void sumByRows(int n, int a[n][n]) { ... }`.  In older C, you'd either have to fix the second dimension (and hence the first too, making the parameter `n` a little pointless), or you'd have to create a more complex structure (an array of pointers to `int`), or you'd pass an `int *` and do the subscript calculation in the body of the function.